# What programming language is Ubuntu Terminal written in?

Tags: language-support

This may seem like a very rookie question for you Linux-users, but I just started using Linux. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what OP meant but I think the answer they might have been looking for was what language is used within the Ubuntu terminal. In that case the answer is by default, bash.

Comment: Is it possible @JeffDror was right?  Doesn't make much sense that a 'rookie' would care about the language used to write the terminal program, but you very well might need to know "This is bash" so you can look up basic commands.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`gnome-terminal`, the standard terminal in Ubuntu, is  mainly written in C.

You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/tree/master/src).

[image]

Comment: "Read the source , Luke", say all the top programmers :)

Comment: For the curious: According to GitHub's language statistics, gnome-terminal is 94.6% C, 4.3% Vala, and 1.1% Other.

Comment: Other is my favourite language :D

Comment: I like the effect when you click the link. It's like if the image went fullscreen and now is a website.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, that's funny =)

Comment: Maybe do something like this? [![enter image description here][2]][1] so it goes to the source and not the image of the source?

Answer (score 8):

The Ubuntu Terminal app, which is/will be used in Unity8 (eg. Ubuntu Phone), is developed at [launchpad.net/ubuntu-terminal-app](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-terminal-app)

On this page is states the languages used are:

> QML, JavaScript, C++

Comment: It should be noted that this is the Terminal app that runs on the Ubuntu Phone OS.